# Excel VBA, nested loops / hide rows based on numbers

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

Dear stackoverflow community

At work I have to write a macro which should be able to hide rows based on numbers in a column. Those can be multiple ones in one cell and the input should also allow to show more than one number at a time.

```
for example:
row 1: 20, 30, 15
row 2: 20
row 3: 13, 76
```

So if I enter 20, 30, it should only show rows 1 & 2)

I usually code with Java / c# and Im new to VBA, so Id really appreciate help:

My plan was to show a input box and split those numbers into an array. 
Then i wanna go through each row with a for-Loop, in which i added two for each loops to check if any numbers equal. If not, hide row. If so, show and then i want to exit both for each loops and go to the next row. To exit nested loops, i tried using a do while boolean but it doesnt seem to work.

Right now it only shows the rows with all the input numbers (only row1 in example).

```
 Sub SortingTest()

Dim numbers() As String
myNum = Application.InputBox("Enter BKPS (separate multiples by , )")
numbers = Split(myNum, ",", -1, compare)

'Userinput Vars
Dim row As Integer
row = 1
Dim saveNumber As String

'Looping Vars
Dim existingNum As String
Dim existingNumsArray() As String
Dim checkRows As Long
Dim saveElement As String
Dim done As Boolean
done = False


' Range("B3").Value = 10
' Saves the Input as Array:
For Each Element In numbers
    saveNumber = Element
    Cells(2, row).Value = saveNumber 
    row = row + 1
Next Element


    Dim b As Integer

    Do While done = False
        For b = 1 To 100 'hardcoded, should be length of document. b == row;
        existingNum = Cells(b, 3).Value
        existingNumsArray = Split(existingNum, ",", -1, compare)


            ' loop thru input numbers

                For Each Element In numbers
                saveElement = Element

                    'loop thru given numbers
                    For Each inputElement In existingNumsArray

                        If saveElement <> inputElement Then
                        Rows(b).Hidden = True


                        ElseIf saveElement = inputElement Then
                            Rows(b).Hidden = False
                            done = True
                            Exit For
                        End If


                    Next


                Next
            Next
    Loop





End Sub
```

Comment: There is no 0-indexed row in Excel. So start with `row=1`.

Comment: thank you! still getting a runtime error at the same line though.

Comment: Hmm. It will not solve the problem but the row number has to be the **first** parameter in the `Cells` function.

Comment: just by looks, there is no exit in your numbers loop... so after hitting the last row in your sheet the next loop will error out...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for you answer. Yours hid all the rows, so i adjusted it to show them.

```
Option Explicit

Function ArrOr(a As Variant, b As Variant) As Boolean
  Dim runner As Variant
  ArrOr = True
  If IsArray(a) Then
    For Each runner In a
      If ArrOr(runner, b) Then Exit Function
    Next
  Else
    For Each runner In b
      If Trim(a) = Trim(runner) Then Exit Function
    Next
  End If
  ArrOr = False
End Function

Sub SortingBKPS()

  Dim numbers As Variant, vars As Variant, i As Long, xRows As Range
  numbers = Split(Application.InputBox("Enter BKPS (separate multiples by , )"), ",")
  With Sheets("Sheet1")
    vars = .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value2
    For i = 2 To UBound(vars)
    .Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
      If ArrOr(Split(vars(i, 1), ","), numbers) Then
        If xRows Is Nothing Then
          Set xRows = .Rows(i)
        Else
          Set xRows = Union(xRows, .Rows(i))
        End If
      End If
    Next
    xRows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

By splitting it up it is very easy to do:

```
Option Explicit

Function ArrOr(a As Variant, b As Variant) As Boolean
  Dim runner As Variant
  ArrOr = True
  If IsArray(a) Then
    For Each runner In a
      If ArrOr(runner, b) Then Exit Function
    Next
  Else
    For Each runner In b
      If Trim(a) = Trim(runner) Then Exit Function
    Next
  End If
  ArrOr = False
End Function

Sub SortingTest()
  Dim numbers As Variant, vars As Variant, i As Long, xRows As Range
  numbers = Split(Application.InputBox("Enter BKPS (separate multiples by , )"), ",")
  With Sheets("Sheet1")
    vars = .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value2
    For i = 1 To UBound(vars)
      If ArrOr(Split(vars(i, 1), ","), numbers) Then
        If xRows Is Nothing Then
          Set xRows = .Rows(i)
        Else
          Set xRows = Union(xRows, .Rows(i))
        End If
      End If
    Next
    xRows.EntireRow.Hidden = True
  End With
End Sub
```

by running this code line by line, it should be pretty much self explaining (also knowing you have already some knowledge in "coding")

Still, if you have any questions, just ask ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it the following way:

```
Sub SortingTest()

Dim numbers As Variant
Dim RangeCompare As Range
Dim MyRow As Integer
Dim NumFound As Boolean

numbers = Application.InputBox("Please,list the values in this format: " & _
                                vbCrLf & "{value, value, value, ...}", _
                                    Default:="{#, #, #}", Type:=64)

    For MyRow = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

        Set RangeCompare = Range(Cells(MyRow, 1), Cells(MyRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        NumFound = False

        For Each rCell In RangeCompare

            For Each Element In numbers

                If rCell = Element Then
                    NumFound = True
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next Element

            If NumFound = True Then Exit For

        Next rCell

        If NumFound = False Then
            Rows(MyRow).Hidden = True
        End If

    Next MyRow

End Sub
```

I think it's easy to understand but feel free to ask for explanation.